# ODataConventionModelBuilder sees my List property as a new EntitySet and throws 'The entity 'List_1Of[Type]' does not have a key defined.'

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I apologize if this is very trivial, I am new to OData and I am trying to set up my model.

I have a class like this:

```
public class EventInfo
{
    public bool Open{ get; set; }
    public List<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}
```

So I added this to my `ODataConventionModelBuilder` :

```
builder.EntitySet<EventInfo>("EventInfos");
builder.EntityType<EventInfo>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
builder.EntityType<EventInfo>().HasOptional(x => x.Attendees);
```

But when I tried to run it, I got this error:

```
The entity 'List_1OfAttendee' does not have a key defined.
```

Apparently the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` is trying to turn my `List<Attendee>` into a new entity requiring an ID, but this is just a complex type that I use here as part of the model, it's not a navigation property and it is not used anywhere else.

So I tried adding `Attendee` to my model like this:

```
builder.EntitySet<Attendee>("Attendees");
builder.EntityType<Attendee>().HasKey(x => x.Name);
```

But I got the exact same message, so I tried to change the EntitySet name to match the name on the error:

```
builder.EntitySet<Attendee>("List_1OfAttendee");
builder.EntityType<Attendee>().HasKey(x => x.Name);
```

But again it didn't change anything.

For reference my backend is RavenDB, and I don't use Entity Framework.

I am really confused, the only examples I found are using a collection of complex types for navigation properties only, but here it's just a simple property necessary for my model. Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Attendee` class shouldn't have its own entity set, you can define that it is a complex type like so:

```
builder.ComplexType<Attendee>("Attendees");
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick ! Can't believe I didn't spot that in the documentation ... They mainly talk about the attributes on the Convention model builder section

Answer (score 0):

By writing `HasOptional` you indicate to ODATA that this is a navigation property, which requires a key. If you do not have a key, but merely use the `Attendees` as a plain list as you do with `Tags`, you should not define a navigation property.

When I define such a construct I normally do it like this:

```
// main model
public class Model
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NameValuePair> NameValuePairs { get; set; }

    // other properties ...
}

// complex type
public class NameValuePair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    // other properties ...
}

// builder
builder.EntitySet<Model>("Models");
builder.EntitySet<NameValuePair>("NameValuePairs");
```